# Only one Elasticsearch jdbc input is executing

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have two jdbc inputs in my logstash.conf file.  The file validates and starts fine and I can see the pipeline running.

The second query shows up in the log and processes fine, but the first jdbc input query never even tries to run (at least there are no references to it in the log).

I use an identical template for all of the jdbc settings, so I know that is correct. The only difference is the name of the statement_filepath, but both of those files execute fine in Toad and return data.

```
input { 
jdbc {

    jdbc_driver_library => "/iappl/confluent-4.1.1/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ojdbc7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "..."
    jdbc_user => "..."
    jdbc_password => "..."
    schedule => "*/30 * * * * * "
    statement_filepath => "/iappl/log_conf/current/configs/scania/sql/V02_INBOUNDLOAD.sql"
    type => "V02_INBOUND"
  }

  jdbc {

    jdbc_driver_library => "/iappl/confluent-4.1.1/share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc/ojdbc7.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "..."
    jdbc_user => "..."
    jdbc_password => "..."
    schedule => "*/30 * * * * * "
    statement_filepath => "/iappl/log_conf/current/configs/scania/sql/V02_OUTBOUNDLOAD.sql"
    type => "V02_OUTBOUND"
  }

}
```

In the log, the second query shows up on schedule, but the first one never does, and there is no mention of it failing in the log.

Ideas?

Comment: can you start logstash with `--debug` and see if anything weird pops up?

Comment: It's running as a service, so it's practically an act of god to get it to run otherwise... is there some way to get that debug done with the service without needing root access?

Comment: You could update the logging level of the `jdbc` input [via the API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.5/logging.html#_update_logging_levels) without restarting Logstash